# Cursorfetch Error: Datatypes and number of variables match the select query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, cursor

I'm facing issue When I calling this procedure from my main procedure. Error: Cursorfetch: The number of variables declared in the INTO list must match that of selected columns.

```sql
ALTER PROCEDURE [ABC].[SKIPPED_EMAILS] (@BatchID INT, @Record VARCHAR(20), @SkippedReason VARCHAR(100), @RecordID INT, @TaskID INT, @TableID INT, @EmailCount INT OUTPUT) AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @EmailBody      VARCHAR(4000)
    DECLARE @Subject        VARCHAR(30)
    DECLARE @PersonObj      INT
    DECLARE @PersonID       VARCHAR(10)
    DECLARE @PersonName     VARCHAR(40)
    DECLARE @EmailAddr      VARCHAR(50)
    DECLARE @PhoneNo        VARCHAR(20)
    DECLARE @EmailStatus    VARCHAR(1) = 'H'

    SET @Subject = 'Skipped Emails'
            
    SELECT @EmailBody = Text FROM FLT.EMAIL_TEMP WHERE InformationID = 'SKIPPED_EMAIL'
            
    SELECT @EmailBody = replace(replace(@EmailBody, '[Reason]', @SkippedReason), '[Record]', @Record);

    SET @EmailCount = 0;
    
    DECLARE EMAILREC CURSOR LOCAL FOR 
    SELECT person.PersonObj, person.PersonID, person.PersonName, person.EmailAddr, person.PhoneNo
    FROM [ABC].[PERSON] person
    LEFT JOIN [ABC].[School] school ON (person.PersonObj = school.StudentObj)
    LEFT JOIN [ABC].[Class] class ON (school.StudentObj = class.StudentObj)
    WHERE person.Status = 'A' 
      AND school.StudentType = 'STU'
      AND class.AttendeeID= 'ATTENDEE'
      AND class.Status = 'A'
      
    OPEN EMAILREC
    FETCH NEXT FROM EMAILREC INTO @PersonObj, @PersonID, @PersonName, @EmailAddr, @PhoneNo
    
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO FLT.LOG_EMAILOG VALUES(0, @BatchID, 0, @TaskID, @TableID, @RecordID, GETDATE(), 'MBX', @Subject, @EmailBody,NULL,'',1, 'PER',@PersonObj, @PersonID, @PersonName, @EmailAddr, @PhoneNo, 'N', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, @EmailStatus);
            
        SET @EmailCount = @EmailCount + 1;
            
        FETCH NEXT FROM EMAILREC INTO @PersonObj, @PersonID, @PersonName, @EmailAddr, @PhoneNo
    
    END
    
    CLOSE EMAILREC
    DEALLOCATE EMAILREC
END
GO
```

Comment: Why on earth are you using a cursor here, this whole code could be a single insert statement

Comment: @Charlieface Have a bunch of receipients and Need to make entry for every single reciepients in the EMAIL Table

Comment: OK, so why can't you do that in a single `insert...select...`?

Comment: @Charlieface Could you please help me undertand? Im new to sql

Comment: Your cursor statements are all "balanced" as far as columns selected and assigned. You will need to debug further. Perhaps the error is in your main procedure. Quite frankly, don't use cursors if you don't need them - as already suggested. And a senior anything should be both using and teaching best practices. Get on board.

Comment: I see now that your prior question is a question about what appears to be your "main" procedure - which also has cursor. Do not assume, do not jump to conclusions. It is likely your problem was there - but better to remove a cursor that you don't need.

Comment: @SMor Thanks a lot sir! Im learning to be efficient in database. I did find that the problem was with my main procedure. fetch statement was wrong. It did direct me to the wrong line number though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This does not need to be a cursor at all. Just use `INSERT...SELECT...`**

**First rule of cursors in SQL:** Don't use them unless you have no other option. SQL likes things to be set-based, do batches as one command, not `WHILE` loops and cursors.

```sql
ALTER PROCEDURE [ABC].[SKIPPED_EMAILS]
    (@BatchID INT, @Record VARCHAR(20), @SkippedReason VARCHAR(100), @RecordID INT,
    @TaskID INT, @TableID INT, @EmailCount INT OUTPUT)
AS

DECLARE @EmailBody VARCHAR(4000);
SELECT @EmailBody = Text FROM FLT.EMAIL_TEMP WHERE InformationID = 'SKIPPED_EMAIL';
SET @EmailBody = replace(replace(@EmailBody, '[Reason]', @SkippedReason), '[Record]', @Record);

INSERT INTO FLT.LOG_EMAILOG
SELECT
    0, @BatchID, 0, @TaskID, @TableID, @RecordID, GETDATE(), 'MBX', 'Skipped Emails', @EmailBody,
    NULL,'',1, 'PER',p.PersonObj, p.PersonID, p.PersonName, p.EmailAddr, p.PhoneNo, 'N',
    NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 'H'
FROM [ABC].[PERSON] person p
LEFT JOIN [ABC].[School] school ON (person.PersonObj = school.StudentObj)
LEFT JOIN [ABC].[Class] class ON (school.StudentObj = class.StudentObj)
WHERE person.Status = 'A' 
  AND school.StudentType = 'STU'
  AND class.AttendeeID= 'ATTENDEE'
  AND class.Status = 'A';

SET @EmailCount = @@ROWCOUNT;

GO
```

**I strongly suggest** you declare the exact column names you are inserting into.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the structure of FLT.LOG_EMAILOG but I would suggest that you specify the columns of this table in your insert statement like this:

```
INSERT INTO FLT.LOG_EMAILOG (f1,f2...,f30) VALUES(0, @BatchID, 0, @TaskID, @TableID, @RecordID, GETDATE(), 'MBX', @Subject, @EmailBody,NULL,'',1, 'PER',@PersonObj, @PersonID, @PersonName, @EmailAddr, @PhoneNo, 'N', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, @EmailStatus);
```